# How to include connection.php in Joomla module file?

Tags: joomla

I'm developing a module for Joomla 3.4.5.

So I'm in this folder "mod_helloworld". I have couple of files "mod_helloworld.php", "mod_helloworld.xml" and "connection.php".

How can I include "connection.php" at the top of the "mod_helloworld.php"?

Now, when I copy code from "connection.php" and paste it at the top of the "mod_helloworld.php" it works. But when I put it in separated file, then it doesnt work anymore.

I think there is a problem with my "include" line. I have tried many ways that I found on Google but nothing.

Just few examples I've tried:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/connection.php';

include JURI::root().'modules/mod_helloworld/connection.php';

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/connection.php';
```

I've been trying for an hour and no luck.

Comment: Sounds like explicit DB connection ? you need the DB connect in your module ? then simply use Joomla DB object `$db = JFactory::getDBO();`

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are wrong as they are  not enclosed to start. But this is a working example:

```
include_once(JPATH_SITE . "/modules/mod_helloworld/connection.php");
```